# Dynamic LI order of display

Tags: html, css, css-float

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9m5c/)

In my fiddle, `li` items are displayed vertically aligned and `floated right`.

Now my problem is the order of items, I want to display first `test1`, `test2`, then `test3`. Currently it was inverted.

How do I fix it?

Note: `li` items are pulled dynamically from database.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test2</li>
        <li>test3</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table;
}

ul{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:right;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You can reverse the rows order in you query. For example in MySQL you can add `order by DESC` to reverse the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't float your list elements right, give your `<ul>` text-align right instead. Because your list items are inline blocks, they will follow the rule and line up from the right:

```
ul{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:right;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/Q9m5c/1/)

---

Or, have the elements printed out back to front:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>test3</li>
        <li>test2</li>
        <li>test1</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9m5c/)